# zsh slow doing eval with path

Tags: zsh

I have had a performance issue for quite some time when doing autocompletion in a folder using zsh. Finally, I dedicated some time, to try to understand WHAT caused the problem, and HOW to solve it. Unfortunately, I have to stop in the WHAT, the HOW to solve remains a question mark.

When running zsh in debug with tracing enabled (and disable my `.zshrc.local`), I manage to see it clearly:

When pressing double TAB, doing `$ cd ~/Documents/<TAB>`, I get:

```
....
+_cd:88> eval 'dir=( ~Documents/ )'
+(eval):1> dir=( '~Documents/' )
....
```

The latest takes ~3 seconds to respond.

This happens on every level of folder auto-completion (`cd a/<TAB>`, `cd a/b/<TAB>`,... ), not with `cd <TAB>`.

I have tried to set the `set -o magicequalsubst`.

Comment: Notice `~Documents` rather than `~/Documents`: zsh is looking for the home directory of a user called `Documents`, which might involve a call to some networked user database. (Either that, or some other kind of named directory, but I don't think that would cause any slowness.) I don't know why you'd get `~Documents`. Post a small but complete `.zshrc` that reproduces the problem and the complete trace.

Comment: Do you enable case insensitive or approximate globbing or completion? What's the output of `(zstyle -L; set +o) | grep -e match -e glob -e complet`? Do you get the same problem in `zsh -f`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Line 88 of the `_cd` completion function in current versions of `zsh`](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/5.9/Completion/Zsh/Command/_cd#L88) is in a section that is only reached when the `cdablevars` option is enabled.

With that option on, `cd username` or `cd var` would `cd` into the home directory of the `username` user or into the path stored in `$var` if those user/var existed and there was no `username`/`var` directories in the current directory or `$cdpath`. In other words, `cd foo` behaves like `cd ~foo` if `foo` doesn't exist as a directory (in `.` or `$cdpath`).

Now, that's only something that's done for `cd`/`pushd`. When `_cd` builds the list of possible completions and you have entered `Documents/` so far, it needs to offer you the list of subdirectories of the `Documents` folder, but also, since you've enabled `cdablevars`, the list of subdirectories of the home directory of the `Documents` user  or of the directory stored in the `$Documents` variable if any.

Which is why it's doing that `eval 'dirs=( ~Documents )'`.

Now, I imagine expanding that could be slow if you're on a system that has a large networked user database without  caching for instance (LDAP, NIS+...). `zsh` would lookup `Documents` in its list of variables which should be fast even if you have millions of variables as zsh uses a hash table, and call `getpwnam("Documents")` to retrieve the home directory of the `Documents` user, which is the part that is possibly slow in your case. You could confirm by trying `id Documents` which should make the same `getpwnam()` call.

I would personally stay clear  of that `cdablevars` option as it's bound to give you bad surprises one day or another. Without it, you can always do `cd ~user` or `cd ~var`, and I find it much better to request it explicitly when you do want to `cd` into something other than the directory given as argument.

That `cdablevars` was already in the very first version of `zsh` from 1990, inspired by `tcsh` that does that by default.  It predates the expansion of `~var`. `cdablevars` should be considered as a historical artefact IMO.

As to how to fix the slowness of `getpwnam()`, you could look at tuning the name service database. For instance, if using `sssd`, you could increase the `entry_negative_timeout` setting which determines how long to cache the information that the `Documents` user doesn't exist before querying the backend again. 3 seconds seems excessive anyway for a user database query, suggesting you may have a configuration issue, or that the provider server is unavailable and the fallback mechanism if any is not configured in an optimal way.

Comment: Appreciate the extensive response! Spot on! :) Just as reference and completion to "answer" my question. I have decided to disable the "cdablevars", which didn't know it was enable in my configuration :( To do that: either remove it from the `setopt` in the zsh configs files, or `unsetopt cdablevars` at the end of the `.zshrc`