# Why do I need to use a `cdablevars` variable before it can be tab-completed?

Tags: zsh, environment-variables

I'm trying to use [cdablevars](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_16.html), setting it in my `.zshrc` file

```
# Set directory variables
setopt cdablevars
Home=/Users/benjamin
```

However, I need to execute `cd Home`, or simply pretend to use it without execution (e.g. just type `cd Home/Desktop/`) first before it can be tab-completed.

[image]

In the first terminal window `Home` cannot be tab-completed. Only after I execute `cd Home`. Can I set the variable so it's automatically recognised for tab-completion?

Comment: So it's not `cd` that's having problems, but the tab completion?

Comment: Yes. I should have made that clear sorry. Tab completion works only after I actually use the variable.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you may want to read [zsh slow doing eval with path](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/606389) (about why you may want to avoid using `cdablevars`).

Answer (score 1):

The `_cd` completer for the `cd`/`pushd` builtins will offer the *named directories* that have been added to the *named directory* hash table (see `hash -d` and the `$nameddirs` associative array).

Those are populated when you you reference those named dirs. Even if you run `hash -df` to build the named directory hash fully, it only adds the `~user` entries (as documented).

A typical `zsh` interactive session will have hundreds of global variables, most of which are not meant to contain a directory. Offering them as completion would be counter-productive.

Also note that that `cdablevars` is more of a historical artefact, mostly there to accommodate users coming from `tcsh` and causing a lot of problems including breaking expectations. I would personally stay away from it. See [zsh slow doing eval with path](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/606118) for more on that.

But in any case, even `cd ~Ho`<kbd>Tab</kbd> (using `~...` *explicitly* is much better IMO) with or without `cdablevars` wouldn't be completed unless `Home` was added to the *named directories* hash table.

Nevertheless, if you want to, you can still populate the `hash -d` hash table with all the variables that contain a directory with `hash -d ${(k)parameters}`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Why completion doesn't always work

The exact effect of [`cdable_vars`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-CDABLE_005fVARS) is that it allows `cd foo` as a shortcut for `cd ~foo`. [Tilde expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Static-named-directories) is what allows `~foo` to stand for `$foo` when `foo` is a variable whose value starts with a slash.

The [completion code for `~foo`](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/zsh-5.8/Completion/Zsh/Context/_tilde) doesn't actually recognize parameters. You can reproduce the problem without the `cd` command: `echo ~f`<kbd>Tab</kbd> doesn't complete `~foo` the first time, but once you've run this command, it does.

The reason it works the second time is that successfully using `~foo` adds `foo` to the [named directory hash table](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-hash-1) (accessible as the [`nameddirs` array](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#index-nameddirs)), and this is what the completion code for `~foo` looks up.

#### How to make it work for a specific variable

After defining a variable `foo` that contains an absolute path, run

```
hash -d foo=$foo
```

You don't need to run this command again if the value of `foo` changes.

#### How to make it work automatically

The only way I can think of is to patch `_tilde` to support parameter names as named directories, either via the completion code or by forcing them to be added to the named directory hash table.

Untested: modify `_tilde` to force entries to be added to `nameddirs`:

```
if [[ -o cdable_vars ]]; then
  local p
  for p in ${(k)parameters[(R)scalar*]}; do
    if [[ ${(P)p} == /* ]]; then : ~$p 2>/dev/null; fi
  done
fi
```

Comment: Spooky how we'd decide to answer a 15h old question at almost exactly the same time!